# Como implementar no .ASPX do VB a ação da tecla ENTER como TAB?

Tags: vb.net, vba

Gostaria de saber como implementar no evento onKeyDown do boby do arquivo .aspx para que quando pressionado a tecla ENTER (código = 13) se comporte como a tecla TAB (código = 9). Isso de forma genérica para que possa ser reutilizada em outras telas.

Answer (score 0):

1º Crie a função a ser utilizada na tela ou em um arquivo externo de script´s. No meu caso criei o nome de EnterComoTab, segue abaixo código:

function EnterComoTab(e) 
{
            var evt = (document.all) ? event : e;
            var charCode = (document.all) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;

```
        if (charCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault()
            const inputs =
                Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input.form-control[type=text]'))
            const index =
                (inputs.indexOf(document.activeElement) + 1) % inputs.length
            const input = inputs[index]
            input.focus()
            input.select()
        }
```

}

2º No body do arquivo .aspx coloque o chamado da função no evento onkeydown:
Ex: < body onkeydown="EnterComoTab(event)">